# text box and buttons does not align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

i do not understand why my buttons and text box does not align .

```html
    <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Pic">Picture/File</label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">   
   
<div class="input-group input-file" > 
   <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-choose float-left" type="button">Choose</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Pic" placeholder='Choose a file...' />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-danger btn-reset float-left" type="button">Reset</button>
      </span>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i want my text box and buttons are align smoothly unfortunately they are not. is there any way to do this? textboxs' bottom line is not inline with choose and reset button.

Comment: Check the height of the button.

Comment: its working perfectly. check https://jsfiddle.net/ystvjxx0/ .maybe some other `css` is affecting that

Comment: it works perfect... do you mean you want in side of input button cut as in pic??

Comment: It works perfectly

Comment: yes here but not on my side @Zuber u are  right othr css was affecting

Comment: Are you really using Bootstrap 4? There is no `col-xs` class in it. It's just `col`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these lines. Maybe you need to `override` `css`

```
.input-file button, .input-file input[type="text"] {
  height: 40px; // Change as per your requirement
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ystvjxx0/1/)

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :) @Sarah_Salar